# NullPointerException when writing to an initialized array from text document in Java

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, nullpointerexception

As the title says, I am getting a NullPointerException at `list[i].setName(name);` and I can't figure out why. A Student contains a surname and a score. data.txt is in a format of first line: amount of entries
second line: name (space) score, same for third, fourth etc.
New at Java and on Stack Overflow, so please let me know what other details I should give. The method in question is below:

```
        public static Student [] readListFromFile() {
        Scanner s = new Scanner("data.txt");
        File fileName;
        boolean weGood = false;
        while (weGood == false) {
            System.out.println("Please enter the file name:");
            fileName = new File(getInput()); //user can input their own filename

                try {
                    s = new Scanner(fileName);
                    weGood = true;
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    System.out.println("File not found, please try again");
                }
            }
        int listlength = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
        Student [] list = new Student[listlength];
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length && s.hasNext() == true; i++) {
            String name = s.next();
            Double score = Double.parseDouble(s.next());
            list[i].setName(name); 
            list[i].setScore(score);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: `list` is an array of `listlength` null values. Debugging would have told you that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create an array like

`Student [] list = new Student[listlength];`

then all array elements are initially `null`.
Therfore `list[i].setName(name);` throws a NullPointerException.

You need to initialize the array elements before using them, e.g.

```
Student [] list = new Student[listlength];
for (int i = 0; i < list.length && s.hasNext() == true; i++) {
     list[i] = new Student();
     ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to initialize the array element before using them.

```
Student[] list = new Student[listLength];
for(int i=0;i<list.length && s.hasNext() == true;i++){
 if(list[i] != null){
   list[i] = new Student();
 .....
 }
 }
```

It is a good practice to perform Null check before using any object(say it is a collection,String .etc.)